# NdSolveValue Freeze sensitive to initial condition

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, nonlinear, debugging, infinite-loop

I am trying to solve the following system of non-linear differential equations:

```
(*VARYING PARAMETER*)

p0 = -0.472; 



(*CONSTANTS*)

L = 0.6; 
m = 0.1; 
V0 = 0;   
t0 = 0.208; 
tb = -0.8; 
Vb = 3; 
Vc = 2.111525871219229`;
W = 3* 0.29;
M = 3 - W; 
x0p = 0.14242390713038472`;



(* EQUATION SOLVER *)
{asol, xsol} = 
 NDSolveValue[{a'[t]/a[t] == 
    Sqrt[1/
       3*(1/2*(x'[t])^2 + Vc*Exp[-x[t]*L] + V0 - 
        Vb*Exp[x[t]/m] + W/a[t]^3)] , 
   x''[t] + 
     Sqrt[3]*Sqrt[(1/2*(x'[t])^2 + Vc*Exp[-x[t]*L] + V0 - 
         Vb*Exp[x[t]/m] + W/a[t]^3)]*x'[t] - 
     Vb/m* Exp[x[t]/m] - L*Vc*Exp[-x[t]*L] == 0 , 
   x[tb] == p0 , x'[tb] == x0p, 
   a[0] == 1}, {a, x}, {t, tb, 
   t0}]
```

But I am stuck and I have a bug that I do not understand. If p0 is greater than or equal to -0.472, everything works just fine (I obtain the solutions asol and xsol almost instantly). However, if I slightly decrease p0 to -0.4719, the code runs forever. Does anyone have any ideas what might've gone wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Shooting for the boundary is taking forever.  You're getting complex-number solutions, probably because of the `Sqrt[]`. Is that expected? It might make shooting for the BCs difficult, esp. if unexpected. BVPs can be hard if the BCs are near a saddle point in the vector field, but I don't know if that's the case here.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The problem comes from the Sqrt[]. I should not have complex values. I  added Re[Sqrt[...]] and it seems to work, at least for now.

Answer (score 2):

Out of curiosity, I investigated this question in some detail and found that solutions are limited by `a[tb] == 0` as well as by vanishing of the argument of `Sqrt`, designated here as `argSq` for convenience.

```
argSq = 1/2*(x'[t])^2 + Vc*Exp[-x[t]*L] + V0 - Vb*Exp[x[t]/m;
```

Consider first the computation,

```
p0 = -0.491;
{asol, xsol, sq} = NDSolveValue[{a'[t]/a[t] == Sqrt[argSq/3], 
    x''[t] + Sqrt[3 argSq]*x'[t] - Vb/m*Exp[x[t]/m] - L*Vc*Exp[-x[t]*L] == 0, 
    x[tb] == p0, x'[tb] == x0p, a[0] == 1, 
    WhenEvent[Evaluate[argSq < .01], "StopIntegration"]}, 
    {a, x, argSq}, {t, tb, t0}, 
    Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> a[tb] == .26}];
dom = Join[{t}, Last[asol["Domain"]]]
Plot[{asol[t], xsol[t]}, dom, ImageSize -> Large, AxesLabel -> {t, "a,x"},
    LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
Plot[sq, dom, ImageSize -> Large, AxesLabel -> {t, "argSq"}, 
    LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

(Explicitly using the Shooting method sometimes is necessary.)

[image]

[image]

From the second plot, `argSq` vanishes at approximately `t0`, and `NDSolveValue` can produce an accurate solution.  For larger values of `p0`, including the value `p0 = -0.472` given in the question, `argSq` vanishes in the range `{0, t0}`, and no real solutions exist.  (Replacing `Sqrt` by `Re@Sqrt`, as in a comment above, may give an answer, but it is not an answer to the original ODE.)  As `p0` increases, `argSq` vanishes at smaller values of `t` until it vanishes at `t = 0` for `p0 = -.410` (approximately), at which the boundary condition `a[0] = 1` no longer is accessible.

Next, consider `p0 < -.491`, for which vanishing `argSq` no longer plays a role.  Instead, we find that `a[tb]` decreases to `0` approximately at `p = -1.861`, and the computation again fails.  The solution at `p = -1.86` is

[image]

[image]

Using `ParametricNDSolveValue` provides the variation of `a[tb]` as a function of `p0`.

[image]

Comment: How did you compute the p0 (=.410) for which argSq vanishes at t = 0? Let's assume that t0 = 0.1 such that argSq doesn't vanish in the interval {0, t0}. In this case p0 = -0.472 works, but p0 = -0.4719 does not work.

Comment: @Andrei  The integration domain specified in your question is `{-0.8, .208}`, so assuming that `t0 = 0.1` is inconsistent with your question.  To be sure, it you reduce the value of `t0` sufficiently, you can obtain a solution for `p0 = -0.472`.  In fact, if you set `t0 = 0`, a solution can be obtained for `p0` throughout the approximate range `{-1.8, -.411}`.  In answer to your other question here, I obtained the p0 (=.410) for which argSq vanishes at t = 0 by trial and error, which can be done quickly, because the computation is so fast.  It could, of course, be automated too.